# Google Maps 'Implicit Positioning of the Map' broken?

Tags: google-maps, lua, latex

As developer of the LaTeX package [getmap](http://kirza.kleberj.de/ctangetmap) I got a bug report that some of my examples in the documentation or on [Bitbucket](http://kirza.kleberj.de/bbgetmap) don't work any longer.

Looking into it, I learned that there seems to be a problem with 'Implicit Positioning of the Map' at least for the city of Berlin, Germany. Other examples do work.

For those with a LaTeX distribution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overwrite]{getmap}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{working}
\subsection{Google Static Maps API Example}
\getmap[
    file=api,mode=gm,
    markers={&markers=size:mid|label:S|color:blue|62.107733,-145.541936%
    &markers=color:green|Delta Junction,AK%
    &markers=label:C|color:yellow|Tok,AK}
]{}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{api}

\subsection{Munich, Germany}
\getmap[
    file=muc,mode=gm,
    markers={&markers=size:mid|label:S|color:blue|Stachus, München%
    &markers=label:M|color:yellow|Marienplatz, München}
]{}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{muc}

\section{not working}
\subsection{Berlin (markers)}

\getmap[
    file=bmus1,mode=gm,
    markers={&markers=size:mid|label:B|color:green|Bode Museum, Berlin%
    &markers=label:P|color:green|Pergamonmuseum, Berlin%
    &markers=label:N|color:blue|Neues Museum, Berlin}
]{}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bmus1}

\subsection{Berlin (markers,visible)}
\getmap[file=bmus2,mode=gm,
markers={&markers=size:mid|label:B|color:green|Bode Museum, Berlin%
    &markers=label:P|color:green|Pergamonmuseum, Berlin%
    &markers=label:N|color:blue|Neues Museum, Berlin},%
visible={Brandenburger Tor, Berlin|Reichstagsufer 1, Berlin}]{}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{bmus2} 
\end{document}
```

`getmap` uses a `Lua` script to download the static maps, therefore you must use the `-shell-escape` switch to enable the `\write18` feature!

`pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`

For the given example it creates and downloads the following URLs and images:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=600x400&markers=size%3amid%7clabel%3aS%7ccolor%3ablue%7c62%2e107733%2c%2d145%2e541936&markers=color%3agreen%7cDelta%20Junction%2cAK&markers=label%3aC%7ccolor%3ayellow%7cTok%2cAK&maptype=roadmap&scale=1&format=png&language=en&sensor=false`

[image: google static image api example]

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=600x400&markers=size%3amid%7clabel%3aS%7ccolor%3ablue%7cStachus%2c%20M%c3%bcnchen&markers=label%3aM%7ccolor%3ayellow%7cMarienplatz%2c%20M%c3%bcnchen&maptype=roadmap&scale=1&format=png&language=en&sensor=false`

[image: munich (markers)]

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=600x400&markers=size%3amid%7clabel%3aB%7ccolor%3agreen%7cBode%20Museum%2c%20Berlin&markers=label%3aP%7ccolor%3agreen%7cPergamonmuseum%2c%20Berlin&markers=label%3aN%7ccolor%3ablue%7cNeues%20Museum%2c%20Berlin&maptype=roadmap&scale=1&format=png&language=en&sensor=false`

[image: berlin example (markers)]

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=600x400&markers=size%3amid%7clabel%3aB%7ccolor%3agreen%7cBode%20Museum%2c%20Berlin&markers=label%3aP%7ccolor%3agreen%7cPergamonmuseum%2c%20Berlin&markers=label%3aN%7ccolor%3ablue%7cNeues%20Museum%2c%20Berlin&maptype=roadmap&scale=1&format=png&visible=Brandenburger%20Tor%2c%20Berlin%7cReichstagsufer%201%2c%20Berlin&language=en&sensor=false`

[image: berlin example (markers,visible)]

Here's the resulting [PDF](http://kirza.kleberj.de/sogetmappdf)!

As you can see, implicit positioning does no longer work for Berlin (only images of the Greater Berlin area) - it did in the past (see Bitbucket wiki) - but does work for other areas! Have you experienced similar problems?

I posted this question here for the Google boys. They state it's a proper communication channel. So, bug??? ;-)

**EDIT:**

With Dr. Molle's advice, I get pretty much the expected result:

[image: museumsinsel]

Here's the result a few months ago:

[image: museumsinsel; a few month back]

So obviously, the geocoding for Berlin POIs were "updated" in the past few month and not to better side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not pass addresses, you pass names of locations instead, which partially may not be correctly geocoded(at least did not give the desired result). See : [Neues Museum,Berlin](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3Dneues%20museum%2Cberlin) and [Bode Museum,Berlin](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3Dbode%20museum%2Cberlin)

Especially when you take a look at the result for [Neues Museum,Berlin](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3Dneues%20museum%2Cberlin) you'll see that the geocoder returns Berlin and not a particular location.

As it seems static maps uses the viewport(it's the blue rectangle in the linked examples) of the geocoded location to calculate the area for the map, and that's what you get when you use the Marker `Neues Museum, Berlin`, a map which contains the viewport for Berlin(that's what has been geocoded)

Example using addresses:(**B**ode Museum: Am Kupfergraben 3, **N**eues Museum: Bodestraße 2)

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=600x400&markers=size%3amid|label%3aB|color%3agreen|Am%20Kupfergraben%203%2c%20Berlin&markers=label%3aP|color%3agreen|Pergamonmuseum%2c%20Berlin&markers=label%3aN|color%3ablue|Bodestra%C3%9Fe%202%2c%20Berlin&maptype=roadmap&scale=1&format=png&visible=Brandenburger%20Tor%2c%20Berlin|Reichstagsufer%201%2c%20Berlin&language=en&sensor=false`

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this is the problem. Replacing `Neues Museum, Berlin` with its address `Bodestraße 1-3, 10178 Berlin` returns the desired result. At least almost, now the pin is placed at `Pergamonmuseum`. Unfortunately, I can't use the tool you linked. It doesn't work neither with Firefox nor Chrome here. Does it use Flash? But the viewport was then wrongly changed in the past months. It usally works for POIs. Any idea how to report this to Google?

Comment: I use the tool for years now, I've never experienced any problems. Regarding to the address: some of the museums there share the same(postal) address Bodestraße 1-3(Pergamonmuseum, Neues Museum, Alte Nationalgalerie), to place the markers at the desired location you may use LatLngs instead. Bugs may be reported at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Static%20Maps%20-%20Bug